# How can I update beta testing application on windows phone marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way to update my beta testing application on windows phone marketplace? I was trying to submit the same app but with version 1.1 but site says application with this name already exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to submit a new version under a different name.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh334585%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

> 23.Can I update my application during the beta distribution period?
>
> No. You must resubmit your updated application for a new beta-testing
>   period

Comment: Vote for it: http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110711-app-hub-marketplace/suggestions/2292139-allow-updating-of-private-beta-applications